# PowerBI Matrix showing data from two date ranges

Tags: sql-server, database, powerbi

I have a matrix that is currently based on transaction date, but I need one figure to use the date in the slicer on a different field. Is this possible?

Matrix is linked to the transaction date.
I need a fee column to be linked to the invoice date but the end user only selects one date range.

Data is currently coming straight from SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

A temporary solution has been to import the table twice and line the 2nd import to the 1st based on invoice to transaction date.